# How to get payload / arguments for queued (not yet working) Resque workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, resque

I have a rails app with Resque. If one worker fails, I want to kill all workers that are related to a model, that spawned that worker.

I know I can get Resque.workers but iterating through them will show :idle for enqueued workers.

Doing Resque.queues will return queues as array, I can get their size, but how do I access workers that are waiting?

I want something like:

```
 parent_id = 999
 Resque.queues.each do |q|
  q.workers.each do |w|
    if w.job.payload.args[0] == parent_id.to_s?
      #kill worker
    end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

`Resque::Worker.working` should give you a collection of all the non-idle workers.  You can iterate over them, and call `shutdown!` on the workers you want to shutdown.  I would first `puts` out `worker.job` for each `worker` to see its structure, so you'll know how to check what its arguments are.  So it should be something like

```
Resque::Worker.working.each do |worker|
  worker.shutdown! if worker.job["something"]["maybe_something_else"] == parent_id.to_s
end
```